# Javascript limit text input characters

Tags: javascript, dom-events, whitelist, onkeypress

I am wanting to restrict the input characters for a text box to `[a-z0-9_-]`. However whenever if do this buttons like backspace and the arrow keys don't work. I have found some attempts on this website and others but either they don't work properly on all browsers or they use a black list. For example the [W3Schools website example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onkeypress) black lists numbers. Is there a way to use white list (the one above) and still allow keys like backspace, arrows, home, end etc? Or do I have to add everyone of the key codes that match the keys I want to allow? I do something like this (this is shortened for simplicity).

**EDIT** - Added code

```
 <input type="text" onkeypress="return checkInput();">
    function checkInput(){
        return /[a-z0-9_-]/gi.test(String.fromCharCode(window.event.keyCode));
    }
```

Comment: -1 because you've confused w3schools with a [w3c](http://www.w3.org/) site. I promise to remove the -1 if you correct your answer (I know i could edit it, but then there's the chance that you wouldn't understand [why](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Comment: I know that w3c schools isn't the best, but it was the best example i could find for my question

Comment: @Timothy Ruhle, w3schools is in no way related to the W3C. Please read w3fools a little more.

Comment: -1 for not reading zzzBov's first comment.  Will remove it if you correct your answer.

Comment: Then please press `save` so we can see it!

Comment: Notice that W3Schools is devoid of a `c`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the regex in the example to something like this:

```
numcheck = /[^a-z0-9_-]/;
```

Or better yet, avoid the double negative with:

```
numcheck = /[a-z0-9_-]/;
return numcheck.test(keychar);
```

Then you can look up the keycodes of backspace, etc. and check for them too:

```
if (keychar === 8) return true;
...
```

Or even put them in your regex:

```
numcheck = /[a-z0-9_\x08-]/;
```

Comment: it still doesn't work. Changing it to !/[^a-z0-9_-].test() doesn't work.

Comment: I did in my code....I didn't know i could do something like the last line of code in your example. Serves me right for not reading the whole page on MDC about RegExp.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any code samples, so it's hard to be specific in a response, but as a general strategy, try this: instead of trying to whitelist characters that can be input while they are being typed in, validate the contents of the text box after every key stroke to make sure that it still contains valid characters.  If it doesn't, remove the last character entered.

This approach will allow special keys like backspace, etc., while at the same time achieve what it sounds like you are really after: a valid value in the text box.

Comment: but what about middle characters entered or copy/paste?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can limit the input of characters. For example create a function that checks what is going on, return true if everything is OK and false if not:

```
// return true for 1234567890A-Za-z - _
function InputCheck(e) {
    if ((e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 45) || e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
        if (e.which == 45 || e.which == 95 || (e.which >= 65 && e.which <= 90) || (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

once you have the function, hook it into you input (this is with jQuery):

```
$('#InputID').keypress(InputCheck);
```

You can make as complicated a check as you want, for example this will allow for USD money values:

```
function InputCheck(e) {
    if ((e.shiftKey && e.keyCode == 45) || e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) && e.which != 46 && e.which != 36) {
        return false;
    }
    // . = 46
    // $ = 36
    var text = $(this).val();

    // Dollar sign first char only
    if (e.which == 36 && text.length != 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // Only one decimal point
    if (e.which == 46 && text.indexOf('.') != -1) {
        return false;
    }

    // Only 2 numbers after decimal
    if (text.indexOf('.') != -1 && (text.length - text.indexOf('.')) > 2) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can press any key you like, as long as you keep the **value** from including anything
not in the white-list.

```
inputelement.onkeyup=function(e){
  e=e || window.event;
  var who=e.target || e.srcElement;
  who.value= who.value.replace(/[^\w-]+/g,'');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to onkeypress event.

```
    var code;
    document.all ? code = e.keyCode : code = e.which;
    return ((code > 64 && code < 91) || (code > 96 && code < 123) || code == 8 || code == 32 || (code >= 48 && code <= 57));
```

For browser compatibility, You can add
        **var k = e.keyCode == 0 ? e.charCode : e.keyCode;**