# Forbidden characters in input form?

Tags: javascript

This is my current code it removes all non-numeric characters except $, commas and dots from an input when as user types:

```
<input type="text" id="price" name="price" onkeyup="updatePrice(this.value)">

function updatePrice(p) {
    document.getElementById("price").value = p.replace(/[^0-9$.,]/g, '');
    }
```

The problem is that it removes characters after typing them so if you type A you see it for a fraction of a second before it disappears. Keydown is no good since it runs the script before the input actually changes.

How can I completely prevent these forbidden characters from appearing on the input?

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript limit text input characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534346/javascript-limit-text-input-characters)

Comment: just remember that this will _not_ prohibit the user from actually sending them to the server, so you will need to handle invalid input server side as well

Comment: Please leave the user interface alone. You only need appropriate values when the form is submitted, you don't care what they are in the meantime. Messing with the value while the user is typing is really annoying and an anti-usability feature. In any case, monitoring key strokes does not stop users from entering characters you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- use `onblur` to perform validation when the input loses its focus - the user dosen't have to be aware of this during typing.
- user dosen't have to be aware of this at all - you can perform the validation upon submit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the keypress event and blur event to validate each key and the string as a whole. If you change the input `type` to being `type="number"` then the user-agent will take care of ensuring that the value is a valid number format for you in more modern browsers.

```
// on key press occurs before the text is added visually to the input field
​document.getElementById('price').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  if(!String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/[0-9$\.,]/)) {
    e.preventDefault(); // not a valid character so cancel it
  }
}, false);​​​​​​​​​​​​​

// complete validation for the text that was entered on blur to update price
document.getElementById('price').addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
  var validated = parseFloat(this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]g/, ''));
  // ... use the validated string to do something
}, false);
```

​