# Is it possible to insert a symbol in input type="number"

Tags: html

I need to make a number input box, which will be used to enter cost of certain elements. I'd like to insert a $ in the box, so when a user enters -let's say- 20, it'd show $20. Am i asking too much?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did it *not* work the way you thought it would?

Comment: Could you use like `$<input type="text" value="" name="foo" />` ? Note that `$` is **outside** input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the HTML part you are going to set the value of text to `$`

```
<input type="text" value="$">
```

And the JS part:

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    if(this.value.indexOf('$') !== 0) {
        this.value = '$';   
    } 
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

The number field appears to just take numbers.  So you can either

1) Move the $ character out of the input
2) Use a normal text input, and restrict the values entered to just numbers, and the $ character.  To accomplish this, you would listen on the `keypress` event, use the event data to determine which key was pressed, and not allow values you didn't want.  [Here is a useful example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5534346/javascript-limit-text-input-characters).

Comment: I think I couldn't express myself clearly. I'm not trying to allow the user to enter $ in input box, I want a $ symbol in the box when user enters a simple numerical value. There aren't any other currencies involved, so there's no point in entering $ symbol manually.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rather novel approach, boiled down from an implementation I found in an online donation page (hosted by acceptiva.com):

```
<input type="number" class="inputright inputcurrency">
```

where:

```
.inputright {
    text-align: right;
}

.inputcurrency {
    background: url(images/currency_symbol.png) no-repeat left; 
}
```